How to do the average of different categories' data if they are on different scales?
I'm trying to classify a bunch of countries using various categories to make an average in such a way that those with higher values would be countries with a higher strength, influence and power
I used the following categories:

NPI (Economic Power and Military Power): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343392223_National_Power_Rankings_of_Countries_2020


GDP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)


GFPI (actually, 1/GFPI, as it's inversed): https://www.globalfirepower.com/countries-listing.php


Population: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population


Industry: https://www.indexmundi.com/facts/indicators/NV.IND.TOTL.CD/rankings


HDI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index


CW (Influence & Power): https://ceoworld.biz/2024/04/04/ranked-worlds-most-influential-countries-2024/ & https://ceoworld.biz/2024/04/04/revealed-the-worlds-most-powerful-countries-for-2024/

The thing is that both HDI and CW (I & P) are on a logarithmic scaling, while the rest are linear or have absolute values (like the population).
I was thinking about some options to do the average as accurate as possible considering that some data are on a linear scale and others are on a logarithmic scale
Option 1: I was thinking of normalizing all categories' data to the maximum value in each category (as I did in the second tab of the sheet: "normtable2")? But I'm not sure this is correct as I'm ignoring the fact that some categories' data are on a linear scale and others on a logarithmic scale
Option 2: Transforming the logarithmic categories into linear and then do the average of everything. But I'm unsure about which number to use as the base of the logarithm to the power of each data value.
Option 3: Transforming the linear ones into logarithmic and then do the average of everything. But, similarly, I don't really know how to do it because I don't know which base should I use to do the logarithm
Perhaps these 3 methods are equally correct? Or maybe none? Or maybe there are better methods than these ones?...

There is no notion of "correct" here.  Different observers might weight things differently.  You should play with various metrics to see which one fits your goals best.

@lulu so just normalizing all data values to the maximum value in each category is correct (even if some of the original data are on a logarithmic and others on a linear/absolute values scale)?

Well, that might make sense, but again:  the concept you are trying to measure, national "strength, influence, and power" is not defined.  Your metric, if you find one, would aim to be a proxy for it. You should write down metrics that have weights attached to the various terms so that you can emphasize or de-emphasize factors as you look at the rankings they yield.

Are there outliers? Outliers will make any combination tricky, since it's hard to compare something that's four sigma in one dimension with something else that's five sigma in another dimension, especially if those distributions are distinctly non-Gaussian. If there aren't outliers, it might make sense to do some kind of combination of ordinals, just to make things easier. If you're looking for something that might be a bit more robust, I did a project where we combined ordinals with a sort of (partial) Pareto front kind of thingie.
